# scale_size_area utilizing max_size gives plot with points exceeding plot's boundaries

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the following dataset using ggplot + geom_count + scale_size_area

```
structure(list(Quail = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
6, 6), day = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7), Sample = c("AO247", 
"AO079", "AO163", "AO136", "AO276", "AO248", "AO080", "AO164", 
"AO137", "AO277", "AO249", "AO081", "AO165", "AO138"), n = c(8L, 
6L, 35L, 36L, 12L, 21L, 12L, 25L, 49L, 128L, 12L, 14L, 26L, 40L
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), groups = structure(list(Quail = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6), day = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 
3, 5, 7), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 14L)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

The ggplot goes like ->

```
ggplot(DI.varL.Quail.final, aes(x=day, y=Quail)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major =  element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 22)) +
  geom_count(aes(colour=factor(Quail), group = Quail, size=n)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = n, fontface = "bold")) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 40) +
  coord_fixed(ratio=1.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73"))
```

I am getting this plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErH9D.png)

I would obviously like to get the points completely inside the plot. I tried using different max_size(s) but I would like to keep it as 40 since it shows differences much better than using a smaller size. An extra feature that I would also like is to have the values on the y-axis closer to each other.

The posts that I looked at do not address my problem. Please, if you can tell me what I may be doing wrong I would certainly appreciate it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change limits of x and y axis by adding `limits` argument in `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous` and also modify the ratio of `coord_fixed` function to get your points closer to each other on y axis:

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(df, aes(x=day, y=Quail)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major =  element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 22)) +
  geom_count(aes(colour=factor(Quail), group = Quail, size=n)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = n, fontface = "bold")) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 40) +
  coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), limits = c(1,10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(4,5,6), limits = c(3.6,6.4))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73"))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Sweet! Thank you very much! But if I have different values for other datasets in the y-axis this means that I will need to adjust this every time, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I think so, except you decide to fix your max size to 40, in this case, meaning that no points will be bigger than 128. In this case, maybe you can adjust your scale by doing (for y: `limits = c(min(df$Quail)-0.4, max(df$Quail)+0.4). You will probably a little bit of adjustment at the beginning to find the right margins you need but at the end, it will be a little bit more automatic.